# About using Qt to build an LEGO EV3 software

Tags: c++, qt, lego-mindstorms, visual-programming

[LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Education Edition software](http://education.lego.com/es-es/lego-education-product-database/mindstorms-ev3/2000045-lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-software-single-user) is built by NI who built labview, and EV3 software is much like labview software, Visual Programming.

I want to build a software like EV3 software, OS software is just a reference

My current thinking is 3 steps to build this software:

> 1.UI implementation(drag effect and other UI effects)
>
> 2.Turn graphics into code
>
> 3.Transfer code to EV3 brick && hardware communication

My problem is not about programming on LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3, is about how to build a software like *LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Education Edition* or *Home Edition* itself, and others can Visual Program on my platform. I plan to use Qt, but I cannot find a open-source prj to reference(UI is very important).

can u guys give me some suggestions plz, give me a open-source prj url or a related website can both be very helpful, thx very much!!

I want to build a software like this url
http://img.blog.csdn.net/20150727182203357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to create software like this on qt yourself or just find OS qt software that can allow you to program EV3.
Anyway, for both of this cases looking at https://github.com/qreal/qreal might be useful (readme and docs are mostly in Russian but the code itself and compiled program are in English).

It is project on Qt that allows you to create your own visual languages and such. On top of that there is qreal::robots (TRIKStudio) which does exactly what you might want - it allows to visually program robots such as ntx2.0,ev3 and others and even has 2d simulator to test your programs. [image: example]

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, it's a very good resource, I want to build a software like EV3 software, OS software is just a reference, help me to architect this software. I just have a rough plan to use Qt, but not decide yet (I could program in Java or other lauguage), could u give me some other suggestions, about lauguage, achitecture, whatever  ^.^, thank you again

Comment: Well, all I know that this isn't very simple task. Creating good visual editing software is hard (at least for me) and I know that there are problems with implementing it for EV3 specifically because there is not many docs on it and it's closed source, so some amount of reverse-engineering would be required (to establish protocols formats and etc.). Simply put this is not easy task.
You can try with creating simble block diagram editor. And then generator of C code (I think ev3 uses it) from these blocks. And add new functional blogs as you go making it more complex.

Comment: @Thisisbill if I helped you, please accept my answer.